# Difference of fp16 computing vs fp32 computing in Core ML

Tags: gpu, metal, coreml

I'd like to ask how computation works on iPhone (iPhone X and iOS 12 I'm working with) for fp16 and fp32 Core ML models. I have a fp32 model and quantized it to fp16 with coremltools. The size does reduce to about half of the fp32 size but the prediction time doesn't reduce at all, which I don't quite understand.

I've already viewed the GPU frames with Xcode Shader Debugger. All the buffers seem to show the data are in RGBA16Float format so I was wondering whether the fp32 weights or biases had already been cast to fp16? Also the Pipeline Statistics showed a message that "high float-to-half ratio". Does that mean the GPU converts all to fp16 before computing?

I made a test to MPSMatrixMultiplication with fp32 and fp16 types. fp16 is 60% faster than fp32 in most cases. So I expect the computation can be faster with fp16 as well. Thanks!

*This is the image mentioned in the answer, which shows the GPU frames and the message. [GPU frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqZ4o.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

When Core ML runs a model on the GPU, it does this with fp16 because the GPUs in iPhones are optimized for 16-bit floats. If your weights are fp32, then they first get converted to fp16 when the model is loaded.

On the CPU, Core ML uses fp32. (I'm not sure about the Neural Engine but I expect this is fp16 also.)

Comment: Does that mean fp32 is down cast to fp16 regardless the range? Even if this is the case Xcode still reports the message "high float-to-half ratio" in fp16 model. Also in the fp16 model the Kernel ALU float instructions takes 93% over 5% of half instructions in a CNN layer. Any doc on this? It's kind of black box here and I didn't find any real specs.

Comment: Where do you see this "high float-to-half ratio" message? Note that not all weights are converted to fp16. Biases values and batch norm parameters remain float32.

Comment: I used the Xcode Shader Debugger to capture GPU frames, following this doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/shader_authoring/resolving_shader_issues_with_the_shader_debugger?language=objc. The message shows on the CNN layers.

Comment: I'll add an answer with the image to show the GPU frame and the message. Please see my following answer.

Comment: Thanks for the image (it should probably go into the question instead of being a new answer). Without seeing the actual model, I can only guess that perhaps the data format for the images is 32-bit floats instead of 16-bit. Or maybe this is the message you get when using 32-bit accumulation in the MPS kernel (as of iOS 11.3 kernels can use 16-bit accumulators). But since this is Core ML, you'd expect it to do the right thing. So I don't really know what's going on here.

Comment: Thanks anyway! I'll continue and will update this thread once I get any conclusions.

Comment: @YuanTan Did you ever find anything? I'm wishing I had the neural cores and 32 bit floats right now.